# How do I find duplicates records or values in a file using Hadoop Command?

Tags: linux, hadoop

I have a file in hadoop file system which contains duplicates records/values. I know through program we can easily fetch the duplicates. But I want to try with HDFS command in CLI for the quick result.

Example:

```
apple,banana,mango
apple,mango,orange,
banana,apple,orange
```

In the above file apple occurred 3 times so it is duplicate record.

I want to find all duplicates through command in hadoop using hadoop fs command...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with a Hadoop command alone. You'd need to run a mapreduce/spark/hive/pig, etc. job to do that at scale.

For such a small example, pipe it to whatever Unix command you'd regularly use. For example, if every word was on its own line

```
hadoop fs -cat /path/to/file.txt | uniq -c
```